# Is there any way to show the data fields from content and google analytics reports in view page?

Tags: views, google-analytics

I want to create a view page where I can show/add the fields of content (title, author, content type, etc) and also the fields of google analytics reports api (event name, total views, users, etc.) I tried with view's permission and and also added a module views multiple permission to give multiple permission but it didn't work.

I have already configured google analytics reports module, I just want to add the fields with content data.

Can anyone help me how can I achieve this and also give some references which I can go through?

Comment: Asking for references is off topic for *Drupal Answers*.  Google Analytics Reports module provides some views by default; can those be customized at `/admin/structure/views`?

Comment: We can create views with data coming from google analytics reports. I want to create a view where I can add google analytics reports fields and content fields both. By default we can add fields from one data, either GA reports or content. @PatrickKenny

Comment: In Views, you can add a Relationship from one entity type (the analytics data) to the other (content/node).  That will pull in the fields from the other entity type (node title, content type, etc.). The author details will require an additional relationship from content to user.  However, I have not used the Google Analytics Reports module so I can't say for sure if this is supported.

Comment: I tried adding relationship but it didn't work. I tried creating a separate view block for GA and add it as a view field in other content view page but still facing some challenges.